# Tokenizing a string based on comma - Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string to be tokenized based on the `,` character. Problem here is the string is like this

`-123 abc, 234 def (2,3,4), -456 zyx (4,5,6) and xyz (6,5,4), 789 final!`

After tokenizing output should look like...

```
-123 abc
234 def (2,3,4)
-456 zyx (4,5,6) and xyz (6,5,4)
789 final!
```

How to write the regular expression for this? TIA.

Comment: java. forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tokenizer will not do, you need a *parser*. Regexps are not particularly good at counting, and that is what you need to decide on where to end a parenthesized block with commas inside.

A simple [*Recursive Descent Parser*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) should work in your case. You may want to get fancy and try [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/). It is a great and powerful tool, but it is probably an overkill for simple expression such as the ones in your example.

Comment: Data is inconsistent. I cannot predict how it is going to be. The string may or may not have parenthesis. Count in between the parenthesis is also not consistent.

Comment: @Sriram Try building a simple recursive descent parser, it should provide enough power to solve your problem, in addition to being a rewarding learning experience. The link at wiki shows a small example, it should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You may try a Pattern Match by "," without numbers around it:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\d][,]^[\\d]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    //Here you know where you have the separating ,
    start = matcher.start();
```

Or how about tokenize by ", "? Hope there is always a space after the , you want to tokenize.

```
String test = "-123 abc, 234 def (2,3,4), -456 zyx (4,5,6) and xyz (6,5,4), 789 final!";
String[] tokens = test.split(", ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

Answer (score 0):

It may work just simply like this:

> var string = "-123 abc, 234 def (2,3,4), -456 zyx (4,5,6) and xyz
> (6,5,4), 789 final!";
>
> var tokens = string.split(', ');
> console.log(tokens);​

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HQgV8/

Comment: comma separated by space may not be the case always. I tried it.

Comment: In that case, can you provide some exceptional cases?

Comment: Data is inconsistent. I cannot predict how it is going to be. But ultimately I need tokenize it using comma only. That is the only standard and consistent thing.

Answer (score 0):

One other way is to use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(", +");
for(String my : p.split("-123 abc,      234 def (2,3,4),  -456 zyx (4,5,6) and xyz (6,5,4), 789 final!"))
System.out.println(my);
```

This will find any comma with leading white spaces (one or more).

Comment: comma separated by space is not consistent.

Comment: I see, then what you need is to break the string by the comma, only when there the comma isn't between (), right? One quick way is to break all commas with split and rebuild: 
when you find a ( you starting adding commas until you receive a ), otherwise you put a '\n' this way you'll get what you want but not the most effective way to go.